# Camel - Handle exception with split operator

Tags: exception, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have simplified my use case with an Order/items example.

An order has some items. 
Every item is controlled => An AvailabilityException can be thrown from "controlItem".
After the exception is thrown, item is marked as Ok and next item is handled.

```
       onException(AvailabilityException.class)
           .onExceptionOccurred(ItemProcessor)
           .handled(true)
       .bean(service, "markAsOk");


       from(startQueue)
           .split(simple("${body.items}"))
                .to(direct:controlItem")                                            
           .end()
       .to(successQueue);


       from("direct:controlItem")
           .bean(service, "controlItem");
```

Now I have another case :

When an unexpected exception (NullPointerException, ...) is thrown I would like to stop the process. We don't handle next items and order is redirected to an error queue.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doTry` and `doCatch`

1. ```
   from(startQueue)
     .doTry()
        .split(simple("${body.items}"))
               .to(direct:controlItem")                                            
          .end()
        .to(successQueue);
     .doCatch(AvailabilityException.class)
             ....
             ....
             .handled(true)
      .doCatch(RunTimeException.class)
             ....
             ....
             .handled(false)
             .stop() // stop the execution      
      .doFinally()  //optional
   ```
2. Instead of `stop()` you can write a processor there and use `exchange.getContext().stop();`
3. You can as well add another `onException` for `RunTimeException`s and stop the route.
4. Another possible way is to use the property **ROUTE_STOP** . You can set this property to true in a processor on exception.
   `exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);`